# Define an address to be modified after the compilation of a C program

Tags: c, compilation, hex, exe, patch

I've this little sample C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CIAO 0x15151515;
#define PROVA 0x14141414;

int main(){
    unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *)CIAO;
    long int nbytes = PROVA;

    long int i;

    int cpt = 0;

    char key[] = { 'a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','\0' };
    int keyLength = 8;

    for (i = 0; i < nbytes; i++){
        ptr[i] = ptr[i] ^ key[cpt];
        cpt = cpt + 1;
        if (cpt == keyLength)
            cpt = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My goal is to compile it and then using a HexEditor, find the specific values `0x15151515` and `0x14141414` and replace them with another value.

I've tried with other smaller sample program i managed to do this really easily. Using this instead i'm having some problem. `0x15151515` got written  as `0x16151515` and i searched for `0x14141414` but I didn't manage to find anything similar.

Here is the relevant hex view of the exe: https://pastebin.com/dLi4tfU5

Do you have any clue on why sometimes the value written seems to change?
Is there any way to avoid this and be sure that whenever i write "CIAO" then in the exe viewed as hex I will always found `0x15151515`?

p.s. I know it's not something that you should normally do and of course i know that editing the exe could lead to unexpected behaviour of the program. I'm just doing it for fun

Comment: Why did you include <stdio.h> ? Wouldn't removing it make the exe smaller ?

Comment: There is no requirement or guarantee that the compiler includes constants verbatim. Perhaps the processor has an instruction that takes an 8-bit value (0x15) and replicates it three times into a 32-bit quantity; if that encodes to less space than the full 32-bit constant, a good compiler would use it.

Comment: @Yanis.F sorry, it was needed in previously attemp, anyway it shouldn't influece my problem

Comment: @unwind that's exacly what i though, do you know any hack or trick to force the compiler to avoid this optimization? or else, would a check bit for bit instead of byte for byte work? (Maybe this could become a bit complex)

Comment: That's clearly an XY problem. Why don't you use the mechanisms intended like the linker?

Comment: @D.Rek What you should do is of course disassemble the code, that will help you understand how the C source maps into the generated machine code, and let you figure out how the constants are treated.

Comment: @D.Rek: It's not just the compiler, but chances are good your CPU does not have an instruction to load a 32 bit immediate. Read the documentation, learn the instruction set. But more iomportant: there is no need for such a hack and it's plain useless, even if it worked. You won't learn anything from it either. Instead concentrate on understanding the target,. the toolchain and how build processes work.

Comment: Your program contains no side effects, so the compiler is completely free to replace it with a program that does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An optimizing compiler may make changes to constants in your code.

You can use the `volatile` keyword as a hint to the compiler that the value of a variable may be modified or accessed by something external to the program itself, and thus to avoid optimizing it too heavily:

```
#include <stdint.h>

volatile const uint32_t CIAO = 0x15151515;
volatile const uint32_t PROVA = 0x14141414;
```

Try replacing your `#define` statements with this code and then open the binary and look for these values.

Comment: Exactly the thing i was searching for! Using this instead of #define alowed me to find and modify the correct value in the exe. I really appreciated your help, thank you.